# Current location of user and show nearby Google Marker around them?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have placed multiple Google Markers in  my application in different locations and streets:

```
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759))
            .title("Food"));
```

What I want is to show users only the marker near their current location. For example if the user is in XYZ street then only the XYZ street marker will display

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Viewport Marker Management](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#viewportmarkermanagement) documentation that works by getting the current bounds of the map that is visible to the user, then — based on the map's bounds — a query is sent to the server to get all the markers that lie within the bounds.

> Only the markers in the square are loaded, this reduces load time and
>   improves performance and as the box moves only the needed markers are
>   shown and the rest are removed.
>
> [image]

First, attach a listener to the `map` `idle` event to make it execute a function called `showMarkers()` when the map stops panning.

**`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', showMarkers);`**

Then add the function `showMarkers` that gets the current viewport bounds by calling `map.getBounds()` which returns a object that has the NorthEast and SouthWest LatLng points of the bounds. With the `bounds` information you can send a request to your server (preferably with AJAX) to get the markers that are within those bounds.

```
function showMarkers() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    // Call you server with ajax passing it the bounds

    // In the ajax callback delete the current markers and add new markers
  }
```

With the new list of markers you can remove the current markers, `marker.setMap(null)`, that are on the map and add the new ones, `marker.setMap(map)`.

Hope this helps!